# Get the application settings values (Environment) from Azure function for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am trying to get the application settings values from azure function for python.

I used the below code to get the **Data_AzureConnection** value.

```
logging.info("OS Env")
logging.info("Env value")
test = os.environ["Data_AzureConnection"]
logging.info(test)
```

But I got below result

[image]

Why I am not able to see the **Data_AzureConnection** value?

Is there any way to get the values from azure function for python application settings?
Please let me know if there is a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only shows `Hidden Credential` in the log, actually you can get it in the code by using `os.environ["Data_AzureConnection"]`. It returns the value in the reponse, see my test result below.

[image]