# Using Application Settings Variables in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to use Application Setting Variables in my Azure Function but it's not working. It's seems that the variables are non-existent / not accessible in the environment.

Has anyone ran into this before?

Here are some related article I have read through.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#environment-variables
- [Get the application settings values (Environment) from Azure function for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61485988/get-the-application-settings-values-environment-from-azure-function-for-python)

```
    #this code returns an error
    connection_string = os.environ["leadvalidationlogaudit_connection_string"]

    #this code returns None
    connection_string = os.getenv("leadvalidationlogaudit_connection_string")
    
    # Does NOT show variables in app settings
    print(os.environ)
```

Here is a picture from my local.
[image]

Here is a picture of my Azure portal.
[image]

Comment: > This is because you are printing "os.environ" print(os.environ), You need to print(connection_string) Then it will return the connection string. Refer my SO answer here, Where I have printed credentials from os.environ from local.settings.json- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77668003/using-application-settings-variables-in-azure-function

Answer (score -2):

The solution was to add the variables into my local.settings.json.

Credit to SiddheshDesai

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).